# Searching for a name in a rough array

Tags: php, search, compare

I have in my array

```
name | sexe
jean | H
marck | H
élodie | F
```

i use this code to get sexe for `$name="jeaan";`

```
    $ss[0]['name']='jean';
$ss[0]['sexe']='H';
$ss[1]['name']='marck';
$ss[1]['sexe']='H';
$ss[2]['name']='élodie';
$ss[2]['sexe']='F';
print_r($ss);
$name='jeaan';
for($i=0;$i<count($ss);$i++){
        $pos = strpos($name, $ss[$i]['name']);
        if ($pos !== false)
        {
            echo "yes :". $ss[$i]['sexe'];
            break;
        }
    }
exit('null');
```

I went compart my string  with the array  but my code return null

How i can get sexe for jeaan = H ?

English is not my native language, sorry for any mistakes

Comment: Please show us the output of: `print_r($yourArray);`, so that we can see your array structure

Comment: @Rizier123 are you sexe ?

Comment: @Dagon I don't get that one, either the joke is "to high" for me or it's just too late.

Comment: this code must return syntax error

Comment: i update my code sorry ` Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => jean [sexe] => H ) [1] => Array ( [name] => marck [sexe] => H ) [2] => Array ( [name] => élodie [sexe] => F ) )`

Comment: maybe mb_strpos http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php

Comment: je**a**an != jean. So you want to find similar entries?

Comment: i use mb_strpos and foreach and i have `null ` becose  `jean != jeaan `

Comment: changed mine to use similar_text for matching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just get the column `name` from your array with [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php). Then search for `$name` in the array with [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and use this as key for the first dimension, e.g.

```
$name = 'jean';
if(in_array($name, array_column($ss, "name")))  //To make sure the name exists
    echo $ss[array_search($name, array_column($ss, "name"))]["sexe"];
```

output:

```
H
```

Comment: when i use you code for $name='élodi';
echo $ss[array_search($name, array_column($ss, "name"))]["sexe"]; i have H

Comment: @Ruydo No it does not. Because it does not even enter the if statement. (Did you put this into a function..... ?)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ss = array(
      array('name'=> 'Jean', 'sexe'=> 'H'),
      array('name'=> 'Marck', 'sexe'=> 'H'),
      array('name'=> 'Elodie', 'sexe'=> 'F'),
);

$jean_k = array_search('Jean', array_column($ss, 'name'));
echo 'Jean sexe is: ' . $ss[$jean_k]['sexe'];
```

Comment: Did you really need to use `array_column` ? Because when you execute `$jean_k = array_search('Jean', $ss);`, it also works.

Comment: This way the needle will be smaller as we will be searching only in values that has 'name' as key.

Answer (score 0):

version 2 finds the closet name via the  similar_text function

```
<?php



$ss=array(
array('name'=>'jean','sexe'=> 'H'),
array('name'=>'marck','sexe'=> 'H'),
array('name'=>'élodie','sexe'=> 'F'),
);

//print_r($ss);

function isSexe($ss, $who){
$match=array();
    foreach($ss as $k){
        similar_text($k['name'], $who, $percentage);

      $match[$k['name'].'|'.$k['sexe']]=$percentage;
    }
arsort($match);
//print_r($match);
return current(array_keys($match));
}

echo isSexe($ss, 'marck');
```

Comment: tnky but i went get  the sexe for  'marckk' 'mark' when i use you code i have null

Answer (score 0):

```
$name='jean'; // search string

$matches = array_filter($ss, function($v) use ($name){
                return in_array($name, $v);
            }); // will give array of matches of $name

$sexe = $matches[0]['sexe']; // will give 'H'
```